# Array modifier with rotated object

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I'm trying to re-create a road layout in Blender for use in a game. I've started with a simple piece of road, rotated to match the underlying satellite image and applied the rotation to the object.

I'd like to use the array and curve modifiers to make this piece repeat along the curve.

Unfortunately, the array has a massive gap and a weird offset each time.

The only way I can avoid this problem is to keep the road non-rotated and apply the modifiers at this point. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Blender arraymodifier]

Comment: make sure you applied scale and rotation for your object

Comment: Thanks but I did both of those

Comment: then please provide blend file because you didn't show us all important settings. thx.

Comment: Actually there you shouldn't have applied the rotation. Look at the transform gizmo. The array is going into the gobal X direction. It's also offseting by the bounding box in the global XY plane. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6zIu.jpg

Comment: Thanks, so don't apply the rotation. If I leave it unapplied, it doesn't follow the curve. It's also offset. I can only have it follow properly by leaving it completely straight. I'll see if I can attach the blend